# Bridge video lessons

Tags: bridge, duplicate-bridge

Are there any good introductory bridge video lessons/courses?

Comment: This appears to be off-topic because it is not a question. It is a recommendation in disguise and has no answer per say.

Comment: Still a recommendation question. I am sorry but unless you have a question about a specific rule in bridge that is answerable with citation, it is not the kind of question that fits this particular Q&A format. Perhaps you would have better luck in a forum somewhere where suggestions and discussions can take place.

Comment: @Pow-Ian What about [this question](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3633/is-there-a-good-casual-online-place-to-practice-learn-bridge)? I presume that according to such logic - it is not right kind of question also, is it?

Comment: I would agree; that question is also off topic. Being as it is two years old I don't know why it was not flagged.

Comment: [Please reffer to the help pages for what is on topic](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Pow-Ian Maybe question structure/format is not appropriate, but it is certainly on topic (Bridge is explicitly mentioned at that link).

Comment: Not a video, but worth the time: http://www.acbl.org/learn/ltpb.html

Comment: @Aryabhata Thanks, I already used it - it is really good one. I am looking for video, because I want to show it to other peoples, in order to spark initial interest.

Answer (score 1):

"Join us for Bridge with Shaw Taylor": http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9GQGfdlNYyM

3 hours in length. Starts from very beginning, assumes no prior Bridge knowledge, and finishes with "Blackwood" small slam game.

---

"Learn How to Play "Contract Bridge" the Card Game": http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9yzS_26fICk

Series of videos, starts from very beginning.

---

"Learn Bridge" by Andrew Robson: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGw5trRnIj8

---

"Introduction to Bridge": http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0w6ZKwgErQ

> Australian Bridge Federation brings you an introduction to the game of Bridge presented by one of Australia's premier Bridge teachers Joan Butts.